# Best way to reverse a java.util.LinkedList (in place if possible)

Tags: java, algorithm, list, collections, linked-list

I want to reverse a `java.util.LinkedList<Integer>` using the available methods.
Looking in the methods provided and the `Iterators` I couldn't see an option other than the following:

```
int i = list.size();  
int pos = 0;  
while(i-- > 1){  
     Integer n = list.removeLast();  
     list.add(pos++, n);          
}
```

But surely there must be a better way. I mean it is not a good idea to modify a list outside of an iterator, but I couldn't see how I could use one here without having to create a new list.
Is there a better way?

Comment: There are many questions on this already. You need to search.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use import java.util.Collections;

```
Collections.reverse(list);
```

Comment: Is this optimized for the linked list case?

Comment: Yes, it makes a distinction of RandomAccess lists and linked lists. Look into the sources ;)

Answer (score 3):

There's an api method for that.

`Collections.reverse(yourList);`

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29.

If for some reason you want to do it yourself, this seems the best way:

```
List<T> reversed = new LinkedList<T>();
while(!yourList.isEmpty()) reversed.add(yourList.removeLast());
```

Comment: The second example is not in place

Comment: None of them is in-place. These are just generic solutions they are giving you, they work for any list. But unfortunately, after looking around I conclude you won't be able to do it in-place with a LinkedList. You can look for yourself in its [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java). There is no way to get those `Entry` objects which form the list's backbone.

Comment: @user384706 actually, the api method is in place (sorry, made a mistake in my example of usage).

Answer (score 2):

see [java.util.Collections.reverse(List list)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29)